# Target only first direct match with the same classes among parent and children in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if the title is kind of confusing, but this snippet will explain it better.

```js
function select(event) {
 $('li').removeClass('is-active');
  $(event.target).parent().addClass('is-active');
}
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item.is-active .itemName {
  background-color: red;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
    <ol>
      <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Click first parent, parent will have background red.
Now click second parent, parent and children now will have background red.

I would like to prevent that. If i click parent, parent should only be painted in red, doesn't matter how many children it has.

So what would be the CSS for this? without having to add so many extra classes? in my case, both parent and children are list items that share the same styling.

I was thinking on using :not() ? But that would require to add something like another extra class on every children. Is there other way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just define a `background-color` for the `<span>` elements within the `<li>`.

Comment: Don't know what you mean, but remember that also the children are clickable and i expect them to have a background red if clicked.

Comment: try `.item.is-active{` instead of `.item.is-active .itemName {` .. Then If you need to prevent the `span`s you need to add `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the default click

Comment: That would add a background to the entire list item, though. Not the desired effect. I think i got it working by using ">" on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove global event attributes at each element. Adjust CSS to

```
.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and attach the `click` event to `.item .itemName` or only `.itemName`

```js
function select(event) {
  $('*').removeClass('is-active');
  $(this).addClass('is-active');
}

$('.item .itemName').on('click', select);
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.is-active {
  background-color: red;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
    <ol>
      <li class="item">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh lol you're right, i think i will swap to this instead of what i was doing... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.item.is-active>.itemName` instead of `.item.is-active .itemName`.

See the Snippet below:

```js
function select(event) {
 $('li').removeClass('is-active');
  $(event.target).parent().addClass('is-active');
}
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item.is-active>.itemName {
  background-color: red;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
    <span class="itemName">Parent</span>
    <ol>
      <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
      <li class="item" onclick="select(event)">
        <span class="itemName">Children</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this also works, but i think i will go to what @guest271314 suggested, since it's cleaner. Thanks for your reply :)